# Angular material 2 allow us to make slider with custom range?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Angular material 2 allow us to make slider with custom range?

for example I need to show organisation size with different range like,

```
1-10 employees
11-50 employees
51-200 employees
201-500 employees
501-1,000 employees
1,001-5,000 employees
5,001+ employees
```

> https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview

shows minimum options. Is there any way to implement these variable range ?

Comment: I was looking for a while for the same and did not find it. It seems to me it's not possible, but I'll be happy to see the answer, too :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your need, do you need several sliders with different min/max?

Comment: I am looking a single slider with variable steps. steps are like 1, 11, 51..etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine that you want your steps to be constants (it would be a really bad UX if the steps actually reflected the real difference between the options). I've put together a quick example that uses a standard `mat-slider`, whose value is bound to the different org sizes in a switch case.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9unenq)

Comment: Awesome.This seems like the best way to do it.